# Wordpress not changing the image height

Tags: php, css, wordpress

This question has been asked many times but none of the solutions are working for me.

I am trying to align three simple images as shown in the image below.

[image]

The first image is sized properly but I am having problems re-sizing remaining two images.

I need to re-size these images to 190 x 157 but WordPress always assigns wrong height of 90px.

I have already registered custom thumbnail size but this doesn't work.

```
add_image_size( 'homepage-slider-image-thumb-big', 190, 157, true );
```

I have also tried to set the dimensions using CSS but the images are stretched out.

Can anyone please help me with this?

**UPDATE:** Here's how I am calling the custom size.

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'homepage-slider-image-thumb-big', array('alt' => $post->post_title));
```

And here's the mark up generated by above code.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 top-post-thumbs">
  <div class="col-lg-12 post-thumb-big">
    <img width="388" height="185" src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/10674399254_eb68aaa18b_k-702x336.jpg" class="attachment-388x210x1 wp-post-image" alt="Demo post 23">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 post-thumb-small">
    <img width="190" height="90" src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/FIFA-sponsors-Brazil-2014-702x336-300x143.jpg" class="attachment-190x157x1 wp-post-image" alt="Demo post 1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 post-thumb-small">
    <img width="190" height="90" src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/falconet-praying-702x336-300x143.jpg" class="attachment-190x157x1 wp-post-image" alt="Demo post 5">
  </div>

</div>
```

Here's the CSS using which I tried to fix this.

```
.top-post-thumbs img {
    width: 388px !important;
    height: 185px !important;
}

.top-post-thumbs img {
    width: 195px !important;
    height: 157px !important;
}
```

Comment: So you want the two smallest images to be 157px high...I'm guessing you're ok with them being cropped by the scaling, correct?

Comment: @rnevius you are correct.

Comment: Really easy to do via CSS. It would be helpful to see some HTML/CSS code for that subsection.

Comment: What size are you uploading the images at? WP only reduces images in size. If your uploaded image is 90px tall it won't create one at 157px tall.

Comment: @Samantha I already know that. The images I am uploading are over 2K.

Comment: Please can you post your template code where you are using the image, along with the HTML it outputs?

Comment: @Samantha Updated the questions with the details you asked.

Comment: Looks like WordPress isn't returning the image at the right size at all, even the one you say is working correctly is returning an image at the wrong dimensions. Are you using any plugins that might affect image output? Perhaps for retina images? If so try disabling that and see if it returns the right size.

Comment: You need to regenerate the images after you add the `add_image_size( 'homepage-slider-image-thumb-big', 190, 157, true );` or upload the image from the start.

Comment: @Samantha I am not using any plugins.

Comment: @Shibi Images were uploaded after adding the image sizes.